# Is it possible to change default waiting time for an action to be executed in codeception?

Tags: codeception

I would like to reduce the time, that Codeception waits for an action to be executed.

For example, if broken link is clicked, Codeception will wait approximately 1m before failing the test. How can I change this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Could it be caused by this issue https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2511 ?

Comment: No, I just want a setting to tweak the amount of time codeception waits for an operation such as click on a link, before it moves on. that's all

Comment: Have you set the wait parameter for WebDriver? Set it to 0. http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#Example-acceptancesuiteyml

Comment: @Naktibalda it's already set to 0 by default, according to the codecept docs. Also that option is responsible for "implicit wait" - the time webdriver will wait when a DOM object is not immediately available([Selenium docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that `request_timeout` needs to be inserted into acceptance.suite.yml like so:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: 'somewebsite.com'
            browser: phantomjs
            request_timeout: 10
```